# dplyr::mutate() return "Error in Ops.factor(gene_id$symbol, x) : level sets of factors are different"

Tags: r, dplyr

My data

```
gene_list <- data.frame(mouse_gene = c("Ccnb1", "Cdk1", "Cdh3", "Cdkn1c"),
                    human_gene = c("SLCO2B1", "PPP1R3C", "MMP13", "CLEC6A"))

gene_id <- data.frame(gene_id = c("23334", "100001", "12341236", "34553433", "22998", "123121213"),
                  symbol = c("SLCO2B1", "PPP1R3C", "FX-232", "MMP13", "CLEC6A", "CSCCD"))
```

I want to add a column in gene_list that can find the corresponding gene_id of human_gene, so I defined a function

```
find_geneID <- function(x){
      ID <- gene_id[which(gene_id$symbol == x),1]
      return(ID)
}
```

Then I use dplyr::mutate

```
gene_list <- gene_list %>% mutate(find_geneID(human_gene))
```

However, I get a return

```
Error in Ops.factor(gene_id$symbol, x) : level sets of factors are different
```

I know that I can use join in this case. However, I would like to know what should I do if I need to use a function in dplyr::mutate.

Besides, sometimes when I want to use a value in one column, input into a function, and put into a new column, I will get

```
Column `new_column` must be length 568 (the number of rows) or one, not 2
```

Can someone tell me the reason? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `==`,  use `match` to get the index because `==` does an elementwise comparison and it would create an issue in the `length` if both dataset have different number of rows i.e. it is comparing row1 of first to row1 on second, row2 -> row2, row3 -> row3 and the values can be anywhere in the column which would be likely missed when we do `==`

```
find_geneID <- function(x) {gene_id$gene_id[match(gene_list[[x]], gene_id$symbol)]}
gene_list %>% 
       mutate(gene_id = find_geneID('human_gene'))
#  mouse_gene human_gene  gene_id
#1      Ccnb1    SLCO2B1    23334
#2       Cdk1    PPP1R3C   100001
#3       Cdh3      MMP13 34553433
#4     Cdkn1c     CLEC6A    22998
```

Also, make sure that the columns are `character` class instead of `factor` by using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while constructing the datasets

---

It could be done easily with a join

```
left_join(gene_list, gene_id, by = c('human_gene' = 'symbol'))
#  mouse_gene human_gene  gene_id
#1      Ccnb1    SLCO2B1    23334
#2       Cdk1    PPP1R3C   100001
#3       Cdh3      MMP13 34553433
#4     Cdkn1c     CLEC6A    22998
```

#### data

```
gene_list <- data.frame(mouse_gene = c("Ccnb1", "Cdk1", "Cdh3", "Cdkn1c"),
                    human_gene = c("SLCO2B1", "PPP1R3C", "MMP13", "CLEC6A"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

gene_id <- data.frame(gene_id = c("23334", "100001", "12341236", 
    "34553433", "22998", "123121213"),
                  symbol = c("SLCO2B1", "PPP1R3C", "FX-232", 
     "MMP13", "CLEC6A", "CSCCD"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I get an error  Error in `[.data.frame`(gene_id, gene_id$symbol %in% x) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: @pill45 one thiing i noticed in your functioin is that you are returning the matching elements, but the length would be different than the number of rows of gene_list.  What is your expected output.  Should that be a list output

Comment: @pill45 or a string column? `gene_list %>% mutate(new = toString(human_gene[human_gene %in% gene_id$symbol]))`

Comment: I just want the corresponding gene_id of a symbol, like SLC02B1 return 23334; MMP13 return 34553433

Comment: @pill45 then just do a join

Comment: Thank you. However, if I want to use a value of one of the column, input into a function, and add the result into a new column, what should I do?